# Save large WP_Query to transient === false

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic, cache, transient

I try to save a WP_Query to a transient but it's always comes back false dispite the fact that the transient is saved.

Here is the code:

```
$fitsToTransientName = 'g_wc_fits_to_' . get_the_ID();
$fitsToTransient = get_transient($fitsToTransientName);

if (false === $fitsToTransient) {
    echo "Test";

    $argsFits = array(
        'post_type'         => 'product',
        'no_found_rows'     => true,
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'accessories',
                'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );

    $fitsToTransient = new WP_Query($argsFits);
    
    set_transient($fitsToTransientName, $fitsToTransient, DAY_IN_SECONDS);
}

$queryFitsTo = $fitsToTransient;

if ($queryFitsTo->have_posts()) { ... // And here goes the loop
```

Here what I know:

- The line "Test" always echos witch tells me that the $fitsToTransient always is false
- If I var_dump $fitsToTransient it's always just: false
- If I use WP Cli and search for the transient, I can clearly see that it's there and har the full query stored correctly.
- Query Monitor does not tell me that there has been a new transient saved (exept for the first time when it's aqually created).

I've run out of things to try out now and was hoping anyone has any good ideas why it's always "false" and how to fix it.

Comment: You shouldn't save `WP_Query` objects to transients, even if it worked as you expected it would have a massive performance hit. WP primes a lot of caches when you do a `WP_Query` so when you retrieve this transient, none of that data has been primed, resulting in hundreds of tiny queries ( e.g. for individual post meta that would normally have been fetched all at once ). I ***STRONGLY*** recommend against this. Instead cache a list of post IDs, and use them to run a much faster query

Comment: Also, that `accessories` post meta should be a taxonomy, it would speed up the query significantly and you wouldn't need to cache it